# How to do a case-insensitive array_contains clause in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive query that looks something like this:

```
select * from table_name where array_contains(field_name, '${some_variable}');
```

This works with no issues, but is case sensitive. I need it to be case insensitive, but both

```
select * from table_name where array_contains(lower(field_name), '${some_variable}');
```

and

```
select * from table_name where array_contains(lcase(field_name), '${some_variable}');
```

fail with a null pointer exception. Is there a way to make this query case-insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (select array('X','y','Z') as field_name, 'Y' as var)
select  array_contains(split(lower(concat_ws('\u0001',field_name)),'\u0001'),lower(var))
from    t
```

or

```
with t as (select array('X','y','Z') as field_name, 'Y' as var)
select  concat_ws('\u0001',field_name) rlike concat('(?i)(^|\\x01)',var,'(\\x01|$)')
from    t
```